# Can't install SQL server 2017 or 2019 on a new windows 11

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

Could anyone provide some assistance? We can't install SQL Server 2017 or 2019 on a brandnew Windows 11 pc. We have removed all SQL applications, rebooted and tried again. We had the IT of the customer remove and reinstall Windows after a formatting of the hard disc and tried again after, always the same errors.

System specs are: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U 2.10GHz with 8GB RAM

We get error 0x851A001A in event viewer application log, but "fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo c:" shows the size is 4096.

In SQL Server setup we get the error: "Wait on database engine recovery handle failed check the sql server error log for potential causes"

And in the Log of 2019 for instance we get this:

```
  
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18) (KB5017593) - 15.0.4261.1 (X64) 
    Sep 12 2022 15:07:06 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 22621: ) (Hypervisor)

2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      UTC adjustment: 2:00
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      All rights reserved.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      Server process ID is 7464.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      System Manufacturer: 'LENOVO', System Model: '20YG00B6MB'.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.OXYGEN2\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQL$OXYGEN2'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.OXYGEN2\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.OXYGEN2\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.OXYGEN2\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2022-10-05 14:03:48.75 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "OXYGEN2"
     -m "SqlSetup"
     -T 4022
     -T 4010
     -T 1905
     -T 3701
     -T 8015
2022-10-05 14:03:48.76 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 6 cores per socket and 12 logical processors per socket, 12 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.76 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.76 Server      Detected 6986 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.76 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.76 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.84 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 524288 bytes for 378182 hashPages.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.84 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2022-10-05 14:03:48.87 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.90 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.93 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2022-10-05 14:03:48.93 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2022-10-05 14:03:48.93 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 328 at 5/10/2022 14:03:46 (local) 5/10/2022 12:03:46 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.94 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.94 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.95 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.96 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'
2022-10-05 14:03:48.96 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: disabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 2. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 Server      clwb is selected for pmem flush operation.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 spid10s     Warning ******************
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 spid10s     SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.97 spid10s     Starting up database 'master'.
2022-10-05 14:03:48.99 spid10s     There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.OXYGEN2\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
2022-10-05 14:03:49.05 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2022-10-05 14:03:49.13 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
```

Answer (score 1):

For systems running Windows 11, some storage devices and new device drivers will display a disk sector size larger than the supported 4 KB sector size.

When this occurs, SQL Server cannot start because of an unsupported file system. SQL Server currently supports sector storage sizes of 512 bytes and 4 KB.

You can fix the problem by running the command:

```
fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo <volume pathname>
```

Example:

```
fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo E:
```

Look for the value PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity, returned in bytes. A value of 4096 indicates a sector storage size of 4 KB.

If you are still having problems running SQL server, then you can follow the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size#resolutions).